# Android SDK Manager Package Installation getting java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: android-sdk-tools

Am trying to install Android SDK manager packages using SDK_tool for Windows_10.
followed Below steps.

**step1**:Downloaded SDK_tool

**step2**:in command promp :sdkmanager.bat "platform-tools"

After this am getting Java.net.socketExeption connection reset exception

```
Warning: Failed to download any source lists!
Warning: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Warning: Failed to find package platform-tools
[===                                    ] 10% Computing updates...
```

please help for this issue.

Comment: why you tag it `android studio` if your question is not related to AS?